# PHP OOP: How Many Classes To Create

Tags: php, oop

Currently, I've created 2 classes: Students and Courses. All we're going to focus on here are the proficiencies. So, each course_type has their own set of proficiencies (saved in course_proficiencies - and each course has a course type). Once a student signs up for a course, I want to be able to track how many proficiencies they have completed (once a student completes a proficiency, a row is added to student_proficiencies).

[a schema http://slickrocksolutions.com/test/schema.png](http://slickrocksolutions.com/test/schema.png)

Now.. In order to get proficiencies(and completed proficiencies), should I create a new class called StudentProficiencies with getCourseProficiencies() and getCompletedProficienciesByStudent($studentID), or, should I do something:

```
$course->getCourseProficiencies();
$student->getCompletedProficiencies($courseId);
```

And, how would you recommend me adding a proficiency? If I don't create a new class, it could be:

```
$student->completeProficiency($proficiencyId, $courseId);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Naming convention: Unlike table names (and some would argue on that too), class names should really be singular, e.g. `Student` and `Course`.

Comment: I think it is perfectly fine to take some short-cuts. Typically you don't need to create classes for connection tables like `student_proficiencies`

Comment: They are. The classes are: Student and Course

Comment: *'Currently, I've created 2 classes: Students and Courses.'*

Comment: Yes. There was an error in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three classes:

Student,
Course,
Proficiency

Course_type is a property of Course.

hash tables as follows: 
course_type_to_proficiency,
course_to_student,
course_to_course_type

I think that should allow you to do a Student method to look up proficiencies with a query similar to this:

Student->get_proficiencies( // connec to DB etc, 
  'SELECT cttp.proficiencies FROM course_type_to_proficiency cttp INNER JOIN course_to_course_type ctct ON cttp.course_type_id = ctct.course_type_id INNER JOIN course_to_student cts ON ctct.course_id = cts.course_id WHERE student_id = ###'

No need to make course type it's own class unless it doesn more than just join courses, students, and proficiencies. If you need to track a completed field per course, or course_type create another hash table with for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need such classes:

1. Student
2. Course
3. CourseType
4. CourseProfiency
5. StudentProfiency

As for methods... Try write simple use-case for your model - it help you to see what interfaces (methods) your classes really need.

---

As for `StudentProfiency`. It can be implementation of Repository pattern, which helps you retrieve some class instances (concrete objects) by some concrete parameters.

Comment: How would you like everything together? Would it be something like:

$student = new Student($mysqli, $studentId);
$course = new Course($mysqli, $courseId);
$sp = new StudentProfiency($student, $course); // pass just the IDs or the objects?
$sp->add($proficiencyId);

Comment: Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern
For example, you can see how this pattern implemented in Yii framework.

Comment: imho this is only appropriate if you're modeling tables as in an ORM.  otherwise, the first class objects are as samtresler describe

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preferences, I prefer to use a class per general entity, going with Student and Courses was a good start.

If you find yourself having a method that does not relate to the object, creating a static object as a "toolbox" isn't a bad idea either to fetch students for example.

To get proficiencies(and completed proficiencies), I'd create methods for each class to obtain proficiencies that fetches from student_proficiencies and couse_proficiencies accordingly.

student_proficiencies and couse_proficiencies should however have a foreign key to a proficiencies table to avoid duplications if they are of same values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified the 2 data entities in your use case, viz. `Student` and `Course`. All other tables in your relationship are normalized forms of these 2 entities. Note that the syntax is in `C#`, please translate accordingly.

```
class Student
{
    // To uniquely identify each student. This is not the same as the id
    // that you use in your Student table. 
    public string RegistrationId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public Course Course {get; set;}
    public Proficiency {get; set;}

    // Get the list of courses completed by this student
    public IEnumerable<Course> GetCompletedProficiencies()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Add a completed course
    public bool AddCompletedProficiency(Course completedCourse)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Course
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

Some changes are required in the database though. In the `Student` table, each student should be referred by an unique identifier that is decipherable to humans (hence the `RegistrationId`), this is not the same as the `id` that you use for maintaining the primary key of your `Student` table.

The `id`s that are used as primary keys are usually integers and are to be known only to the database system (and is usually an [AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) [Integer](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) field). The `RegistrationId` should be something that can include the `University Name`, `School Name`, `Year of Admission`, `Alphabetical Order of Student's name`, etc.

Same identification `Id` will also apply to the `Course` class.

The methods `GetCompletedProficiencies()` and `AddCompletedProficiency()` encapsulate the operations on the database.

A suggestion for `OOP` would be to be first to identify the classes in your use case or requirement, before going in for the database design part.

**More information**

- [How do you design object oriented projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100819/how-do-you-design-object-oriented-projects)
- [What books do you suggest for understanding object oriented programming design deeply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574001/what-books-do-you-suggest-for-understanding-object-oriented-programming-design-d)
- [simple explanation PHP OOP vs Procedural?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural)
- [What's the point of OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270/whats-the-point-of-oop)